# When to use `prototype` in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

When I apply functions like `filter` or `forEach` to an array, I don't use the word `prototype` to call it. I would just code `arr.filter(x => x > 1)`, not `arr.prototype.filter(x => x > 1)`.

However, I saw a leetcode solution that uses a map, and uses `prototype`. The solution uses map like so:

```
var Leaderboard = function() {
    this.map = new Map();
};
```

The solution created its own method called `addScore` like so:

```
// Why doesn't it just say "addScore = function(...) {" ??
Leaderboard.prototype.addScore = function(playerId, score) {
    if (this.map.has(playerId)) {
        const val = this.map.get(playerId);
        score = val + score;
    } 
    
    this.map.set(playerId, score);
};
```

Is this how maps work? or is this how custom functions work?
Why and when do we have to use prototype?

Comment: start with e.g. some MDN documentation ... [Inheritance with the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#inheritance_with_the_prototype_chain) and [Different ways to create objects and the resulting prototype chain :: With a constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#with_a_constructor)

Comment: The difference is between *defining* the method and *using* the method (on a particular instance). Notice that `Array.prototype.filter` etc are defined in exactly the same way.